# Firebase Cloud Messaging - push notification not received

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I' a little struggling with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Main language is PHP and I use the REST api.

I want to send a push notification on a browser ( myne for test ), something like the one which can send with the Notification Web Api ( new Notification("Hi there!") ).
I can see in the messaging/reports page of Firebase that a new notification has been sen, but it's never received.

My steps, after all the Firebase app registration and token generating to access it :

1. I generate the device token with the JS SDK at this time.
2. Once I get the device token, I use it with a curl request with this endpoint : https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/messages:send to send a notification.
   At this step, what I understood is that the FCM app receive the request and send the notification to the browser identified by the token. So that was the final step.
   Did I miss something ?

Here's the curl request :

```php
<?php
require_once 'conf/conf.inc.php';
function getUserToken( $userId )
{
    return htmlentities($_POST['tokenDest']);
}

$messageFields = [
    'token'     => getUserToken(3),
    "notification" => [
        "body" => "Vous avez recu blabla",
        "title" => "Notification blabla"
    ],
    "webpush" => [
      "headers" => [
        "Urgency" => "high"
      ]
    ],
    "data" => [
      "volume" => "3.21.15",
      "contents" => "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
    ],
];
$fields = [
    "message" => $messageFields,
];
$curl = curl_init();
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/messages:send',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode( $fields ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . BEARER_TOKEN
    ),
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
echo $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS];
//
curl_exec($curl);
// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($curl))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
}
```

Thanks by advance for all your help.